# Passing a pipeline variable into ARM template

Tags: powershell, variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am looking to take a name in a text file, set it as a variable, and then pass this variable into an ARM template so that when a resource is deployed it includes the name from the text file.

Currently my YAML file is set to start with a PS command for setting a variable and reading the text file within my repository.

- `task: PowerShell@2`
  `inputs:`
  `targetType: 'inline'`
  `script: 'Get-Content -Path $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/ClientListTest.txt;Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=clientname]"'`

After that I have an ARM template deployment for an SQL server and would like to pass the set variable of the client name into the template so that the SQL server name includes the variable.

Would I need to add a variable field into the template and if so how do I link the PS/pipeline variable into there?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Hi, I was able to resolve this, thanks for the help. I did have to include something additional in the powershell script for everything to work which I replied to below in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would I need to add a variable field into the template and if so how do I link the PS/pipeline variable into there?

We could create a parameter in the ARM template and then pass the variable `clientname` as a parameter when we use the [Azure Resource Group Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops) task:

```
Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=clientname]clientnameValue")
```

The ARM template file `deploy.json`:

```
...
"parameters": {
    "clientname": {
      "type": "string"
    }
}
...
```

The ARM template deployment task:

[image]

You could check this document [Using linked and nested templates when deploying Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates) and [this blog](https://www.timmerman.it/index.php/using-values-from-your-arm-template-across-your-azure-devops-pipeline-with-powershell/) for some more details.

Comment: For solving this what I had to do was set a variable at the beginning and end so that the variable declaration [key:value] pair would relate to the Powershell script at the beginning.

$clientvar = Get-Content....variable = clientname]$clientvar

What this did was first set $clientvar to the name inside the text document (Alex for example) and then the variable "clientname" has the value of Alex associated to it.

You can then set parameters in your ARM template and overrideParameters in the pipeline YAML.